# "Why may a many-to-many relationship occur in the context of messaging?"

Tags: messaging

As the title says, "Why may a many-to-many relationship occur in the context of messaging?". I'm not too sure I fully understand messaging systems and what they actually do. My understanding is that they are just a way of sending messages to X from Y and visa-versa.

Comment: Without further context, this question is somewhat meaningless, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because people can be senders and receivers, and because they can send to many people, and receive from many people.

Answer (score 1):

Think about messaging not so much like snail-mail letter.  Think about a service like a RSS feed aggregator.

This service is responsible for gathering many different messages from many different sources and making them available to many different destinations.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that everyone engaging in a message is referring to as a "Contact". A Contact has_many Messages and a Message belongs_to a Contact. However, A message doesn't belong_to just ONE Contact, it belongs_to to TWO -- the Sender and Receiver, yes?

Imagine a mechanism for storing messages in a table:

```
id         (integer)
sender     (reference to Contact)
receiver   (reference to Contact)
message    (text)
```

You basically have a relationship table between Contact and Contact. However, this is a self-referencing relationship. You aren't connecting two tables, but rather you are connecting a table to itself.

A similar concept arises in social networking, like whenever you add a friend on Facebook. Everyone is a User on Facebook, yet not everyone is a friend. Instead, a self-referencing relational table exists that says "User A and User B are friends"